# How to close Messages.app?

Tags: applications, messages

I'm unable to quit or close **Messages.app**.

Even if I do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, I still see a popup message telling me that I received a message.

I don't want to disable notifications at all, I just don't want to receive messages while the application is *closed*.

I haven't been able to do this? Is there any special/hidden setting to do it?

Comment: Open messages preferences!

Disable the "Watch for my Name"

Comment: that setting is disabled.

Comment: Can you please include details of OS X version and a detailed description of the problem and what procedure you are going through and what ultimately you are trying to achieve. Your current question is a bit obtuse and I fear most people will just be shooting in the dark here. Adding screenshots would greatly help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the notifications using Notification Center. Please note that they will be disabled whether the app is opened or closed.

Open System Preferences, then select Notifications (upper right corner). You will then see a list of Apps which use Notification Center. Find Messages in this list. Set the "Messages alert style" to None.

Answer (score 0):

You can (temporarily) prevent the notification center from bothering you, by option-clicking the icon in the menu bar.  This will turn off all notifications, and not just the messages app.